# Xcode - "Preference Pane" project - how to access bundle?

Tags: cocoa, nsbundle

I have created a "Preference Pane" project. In this project I would like to load an image from my bundles resources folder. This seems difficult because "[NSBundle mainBundle]" seems to return the following:

```
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </Applications/System Preferences.app> (loaded)
```

Iterating through "[NSBundle allBundles]" reveals that my projects bundle appears, but does not appear to be loaded:

```
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Mouse.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Sound.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Spotlight.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/TimeMachine.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </Library/PreferencePanes/DivX.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Trackpad.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/UniversalAccessPref.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Dock.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/DateAndTime.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Keyboard.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/MobileMe.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/FibreChannel.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Appearance.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/DigiHubDiscs.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Ink.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Security.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/EnergySaver.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Speech.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </Users/michael/Library/PreferencePanes/MyPrefPane.prefPane> (loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </Users/michael/Code/MyPrefPane/build/Debug/MyPrefPane.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/SharingPref.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Expose.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/SoftwareUpdate.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/ParentalControls.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/PrintAndFax.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Accounts.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/DesktopScreenEffectsPref.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Bluetooth.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Localization.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/StartupDisk.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Network.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </Applications/System Preferences.app> (loaded)
27/12/10 9:24:18 PM System Preferences[5076]    NSBundle </System/Library/PreferencePanes/Displays.prefPane> (not yet loaded)
```

I'm not sure whats going on here. How can I access my prefpane bundle?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Calling `[self bundle]` within your main class should do it.

Comment: Documented here: http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/UserExperience/Reference/PreferencePanes/Classes/NSPreferencePane_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSPreferencePane/bundle

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to use "[NSBundle bundleForClass:[self class]];".

Answer (score 0):

Late answer but for people looking for a full solution. If you had a image resource in your prefPane bundle named `red.png` you could load the resource by calling the following:

```
NSImage *redIndicator = [[self bundle] imageForResource:@"red"];
```